# How to post data without a form

Tags: javascript, php

Good day sir/ma'am I am a new programmer, I would like to ask how to post data like the functionality of form that when submitting the form the URL in action will display using javascript.

"WITHOUT USING A FORM" or using xmlHTTP that not return to main page

sample is

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="revise" onclick="revisetask(<?php echo $id; ?>)">
```

JS

```
function revisetask(idtask)
{
    //In this function sir i would like to post here
}
```

Im very sorry if my english is too bad.. thanks in advance :D

Comment: Well, you need to collect the data from the UI somehow, throw it into an object, and an XHR doesn't necessarily need to redirect.

Comment: good day sir.. can you please give some sample just a basic output... :(

Comment: show us your code.. what have you done so far.

Comment: sir that only the sample. i try using href but somebody say the value will in the url that can other easy to realize.... so im planning of posting using javascript that same function of using FORM... but my code will have no form instead of pure DIV... 

in my sampe sir, how i can post the onclick value to updatetask.php... using that sample... 

when i click the button it will post and the url now localhost/update/updatetask.php with the value of  $id...

sorry if my english is bad :(

Comment: I just wondered why you don't want to use form in submitting your data? When you also don't want it to go back to the main page? Make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript for submitting the values of input boxes,
to do so,

write a javascript function which will read all your input boxes values into javascript variables,
Prepare a URL, and call that URL using `window.location.href`

```
    function SubmitMyForm
    {
    var Firstname = document.getElementbyId('FirstName').value;
    var Lastname = document.getElementbyId('LastName').value;
    var URL="myDBoperations.php?firstname="+Firstname+"&lastname="+Lastname;
    window.location.href= URL;
}
```

On the operations form you will receive these value in GET.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: sir thanks for the code... i can use that if the value will not display in url...:)...

Answer (score 1):

U can use `ajax` for this. U don't need a form for `ajax` post, and it won't refresh the page too.

Below is an example code

```
<input type="text" id="test_name" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" obclick="save_this()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function save_this(){
 var text = $('#test_name');//stores te value in text field
 $.ajax({
 url: 'http://example.com/test.php',//your URL
 type: 'POST',
 data: { text: text },
 success: function(data){
  alert(data);
 } 
});
}
</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['text'];
```

Comment: (You're assuming the OP is using jQuery)

Comment: good day sir.. sample that code i put it in index.php that post in update.php... then when button click it will not return index.php.. the update.php only will display...

i very of my foor english

Answer (score 1):

As I've seen in this code:

`<input type="button" value="revise" onclick="revisetask(<?php echo $id; ?>)">`

I assume and believe that the reason why you don't want to use form because you want your `$id` to be submitted through javascript/jquery. But alternatively, you could just do it this way:

**HTML:**

```
<form method = "POST" action = "updatetask.php">
    <input type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $id; ?>" name = "taskid" id = "taskid"/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "UPDATE" name = "updatebutton">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
      $taskid = $_POST['taskid'];
?>
```

In the above code I just set the type hidden and which contains the value of your `$id` in which would be post in your Php file.

**UPDATE:**

If it still doesn't fit to what you want then you could just have this other alternative which will be using the GET method: `<a href = "updatetask.php?id='<?php echo $id; ?>' REVISE </a>"`

That's the only option you have. and if you don't want to show the `id` in your url then you could just use **URL Rewriting** (refer to this link: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: good idea sir... I will test this...  i think it can easy to secure this code even it was hide.. :) because of thinking JS function i forget this basic like using vb.. to hide something :D

Comment: Yes, you can assure it's security for the method used there was post which will not require you to put the values in your url unlike the get method.

Comment: No offense but what do you mean by, "it was just like an updating that inside the table that value is in fetch array"? Does it mean that you want to fetch the row from the table in database in which the `$id` is equal to the id of that table?

Comment: thanks sir.. but is not enough :D.. the main reason that it will pass to js because it was just like an updating that inside the table their a column name action that have many button per row that revise button signify the select id of that row.. :D sorry if my english is bad ... slite it was near to my answer :D thanks sir..

Comment: yes sir :D.. im very sorry... if it was not totally clear... im very sorry... im not good in english..

Comment: If that is so, your last option is to use *Get method*. I updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong, please don't feel sorry for yourself. Anyways have you tried it?

Comment: thanks sir for your help.. i think a href is the only choose i taken... or i will just doing pop-up div.. so that it will not go through to update.php :D...

Comment: No problem. Yes that's a good idea also, if you're using some css framework like bootstrap you can just have a modal for it.